# Are the math operators +,-,*,/ strings, floats or integers?(Java)

Tags: java, operators

I am new to java and am trying to make a program that asks for 2 integers and then asks for the operator which then will calculate the result. So far, I can already get the integers but I am having trouble with the operators since I don't know what category they fall in.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class three {
    private static Scanner in;
              public static void main(String[] args) {
          int a;
          int b;
          String c;
         in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter an integer");  
         a = in.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Enter another integer");
         b = in.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Press +, -, * or /");
         c = in.nextLine();
     System.out.println(c);
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can already get the integers but I am having trouble with the
>   operators since I don't know what category they fall in

They belongs to none of these. They are part of programming language and not data type. Data types and operators work along to perform some action like

```
int a, b;
int c = a + b;
```

Even you can have that operator as a `String` but after user input you have to perform check to decide about the operation.

```
if("+".equals(userInput) {// "+" is String
  int c = a + b;
}
```

As mentioned by [`TheLostMind`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193767/thelostmind) in comment, for checking the user input you should use [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) case.

Comment: I would use `switch` for operators.. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Certainly.! I would strongly suggest that as well.

Comment: switch is bad and harmful... As starter, you can use it, but at some point, move to patterns, more precise, Command Pattern...

Comment: yea I just used if statements to finish it off.. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

They're actually methods (albeit ones that are allowed some "special" syntax on account of being operators). For example, you could easily replace `2 + 2` with some function `plus(2, 2)` and they would have the same meaning.

Think about it from the perspective of math - how could `+` *possibly* be a number? Which number is it supposed to be? Would you ever count "1, 2, +, 4, -, 5..."? That being the case, clearly it isn't a float or an int.